# Replacing cell, not string

Tags: python

I have the following code.

```
import fileinput

map_dict = {'*':'999999999', '**':'999999999'}
for line in fileinput.FileInput("test.txt",inplace=1):
    for old, new in map_dict.iteritems():
        line = line.replace(old, new)
    sys.stdout.write(line)
```

I have a txt file

```
1\tab*
*1\tab**
```

Then running the python code generates

```
1\tab999999999
9999999991\tab999999999
```

However, I want to replace "cell" (sorry if this is not standard terminology in python. I am using the terminology of Excel) not string.

The second cell is

```
*
```

So I want to replace it.

The third cell is

```
1*
```

This is not *. So I don't want to replace it.

My desired output is

```
1\tab999999999
*1\tab999999999
```

How should I make this? The user will tell this program which delimiter I am using. But the program should replace only the cell not string..

And also, how to have a separate output txt rather than overwriting the input?

Comment: You showed your code and clearly stated your input. Please try to restate  what your desired output is. The standard file operations in python (including how to write) can be easily searched for.

Comment: @roadrunner66  I edited my question. And I looked up about how to output separate txt but I can't figure out how to. I am really a novice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open a file for writing, and write to it.
2. Since you want to replace the exact complete values (for example not touch `1*`), do not use replace.  However, to analyze each value split your lines according to the tab character ('\t').
3. You must also remove end of line characters (as they may prevent matching last cells in a row).

Which gives

```
import fileinput
MAPS = (('*','999999999'),('**','999999999'))
with open('output.txt','w') as out_file:
  for line in open("test.txt",'r'):
    out_list = []
    for inp_cell in line.rstrip('\n').split('\t'):
      out_cell = inp_cell
      for old, new in MAPS:
        if out_cell == old:
          out_cell = new
      out_list.append(out_cell)
    out_file.write( "\t".join(out_list) + "\n" )
```

There are more condensed/compact/optimized ways to do it, but I detailed each step on purpose, so that you may adapt to your needs (I was not sure this is exactly what you ask for).

Comment: Oh.. by the way I found that this code erases the contents of test.txt.... I want to keep it intact. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: I looked at the python documentation for `fileinput` (https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html?highlight=fileinput#module-fileinput).  I took that part directly from your code, I thik=nk the problem comes from the `inplace` argument. You could replace that line with a simple `open`.  I edited my code.

Answer (score 0):

the `csv` module can help:

```
#!python3
import csv
map_dict = {'*':'999999999','**':'999999999'}
with open('test.txt',newline='') as inf, open('test2.txt','w',newline='') as outf:
    w = csv.writer(outf,delimiter='\t')
    for line in csv.reader(inf,delimiter='\t'):
        line = [map_dict[item] if item in map_dict else item for item in line]
        w.writerow(line)
```

Notes:

1. `with` will automatically close files.
2. `csv.reader` parses and splits lines on a delimiter.
3. A `list comprehension` translates line items in the dictionary into a new line.
4. `csv.writer` writes the line back out.

Comment: @Mark_Tolonen It says "'newline' is an invalid keyword argument for this function" Does it something to do with my using Windows?

Comment: @user42459 you must be using Python 2. Use `'rb'` or `'wb'` (binary mode) instead.  See the `csv` documentation.